# Search for RestASSURED values by sending a variable

Tags: rest-assured-jsonpath

In the following code fragment I am trying to find in my responseBody a specific number by a variable and thus save its brother value.
However when I try to do it that way he answers me null and if I remove the quotes he answers me:

The parameter `"n0"` was used but not defined. Define parameters using the `JsonPath.params(...)` function

```
Response response = get(keyrest);
System.out.println("Value 0: "  + response.asString());
semilla = response.path("seed");
String v1 = response.path("keys.find{it.number == 'n0'}.value");
```